# Recover files from HP recovery partition

Tags: windows-10, data-recovery, partition-recovery

Several month ago i tried to install some graphic card drivers, and it resulted in messing up my HP laptop. After some struggles i managed to reinstall windows.

However, i don't have access to files in the recovery partition.

As you can see in the screenshot below,12 GBs is used:

[image]

However, when i enter `Recovery` folder, it is empty:

[image]

Is there a way to access the files in `Recovery` folder, without restoring windows? (As you can see, its from 19/10/18)

Comment: See if this works.....https://itstillworks.com/reveal-contents-hp-recovery-partitions-9441.html

Comment: Make an Ubuntu LiveUSB https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0 then boot from it and mount that partition along with the partition where you keep data; the matter should be mounted R/W. Then you can use Ubuntu's Files app to copy files out of the Recovery partition.